Can you (and has anyone) answer correctly and still get 100 points?
In the quiz show Pointless you get a point for every person in the survey that gave the same answer as you, and the aim of the game is to get the fewest points possible.
The punishment for giving an incorrect answer is you get 100 points.
However, it seems that since 100 people are surveyed, it's possible they all gave a certain (correct) answer and if you give this answer, you'll get 100 points despite it being correct.
Can this happen? (or are the questions/answers vetted so that it never does?)
And if so, has it happened?

In a word, yes. It's happened several times.

In September 2010, contestants David and Susan received the unenviable honour of being the first contestants in Pointless history to receive 100 points, but not as a result of giving an incorrect answer. Given a list of possible answers, the contestants had to answer with what type of food they thought each one was. Contestant David answered that Parmesan was a type of cheese and was perfectly correct, however unfortunately for him and his wife Susan, all of the 100 people surveyed also knew it was a type of cheese, meaning they scored 100 points, despite answering correctly. However, thanks to a strong performance from Susan, the couple still managed to win both the round and the show - though not the jackpot. Rather bizarrely, a seemingly even more obvious answer, namely plaice being a type of fish, scored a comparatively modest 93.
To date, two other 100-point answers have been given. One was by contestant MJ on 19 February 2013, when the category was "Capital Cities" and the clue "Hosted the 2012 Olympics". (Oh, and the answer was "London", as if you didn't know.) She and her dad survived the round, but didn't win the show. The other was given by Antony Worrall Thompson on a chefs edition of Pointless Celebrities broadcast 31 August 2013, when all 100 people knew the foodstuff omitted from the film title [blank], I Shrunk The Kids. Xander was amazed by this and claimed he'd never seen it happen before - given that the copyright date on the end of the show was 2012, it's just possible that the episode was recorded before MJ's, but you'd think he might recall the previous occasion. On the first pass in the same round, Worrall Thompson's team mate Rustie Lee correctly stated that 'Peach' was the missing word in James and the Giant [blank]. However this scored 89 points, giving the pair a total score of 189, the highest score ever recorded on the programme, without giving an incorrect answer.
UKGameShows - Pointless FAQs


“a seemingly even more obvious answer, namely plaice being a type of fish” I don’t know who wrote that article, but it sounds insane to me to claim that more people know of plaice than Parmesan. Count me as someone who has just learned today that the former is a fish.

@fyrepenguin - Plaice is the best kind of fish to get at a fish&chip shop because the ratio of yummy batter to fish is the highest.

Huh. Good to know. Thanks!

@fyrepenguin I guess you're not a Brit then, because you've missed out on all the plaice/place puns that regularly get used in chippy names.

@Graham while I'm not a huge fan of fish based puns, I do agree they have their plaice
(I'm so, so sorry, please don't delete my account!)

Wikipedia describes plaice as having a "subtle flavor". Leave it to the Brits to assume a bland fish is more commonly known than flavorful parmesan cheese, ha. At least they are often battered and fried.

@ThaRobster Cod knows that's not the sole fish-based pun out there. Although my favourite chip shop name is still "300 Spartans" - because they got battered in Greece.

@Graham While I am an American, I lived in Britain for years when I was younger and still didn't know that plaice was a type of fish.

@fyrepenguin your comment needs exactly 100 upvotes.   No more, no less.

@ThaRobster While a lobster might not be a fish, it is considered 'shellfish' and you are busted. I shellfishly claim the honor of trapping you.

Given the shockingly low scores on most of the extremely easy and obvious questions on Pointless, I’m actually surprised it’s ever happened.

Looks like @fyrepenguin's comment about "plaice" being unknown to many people is going to hit 100 before the answer's upvote count does.  Not being British, I also have never (knowingly) heard/seen that word before.  But, apparently, all English speakers, whichever country they're from, know what Parmesan cheese is.

@jrw32982 - It's pronounced Parm'ee'sian.

Well, definitely the English speakers I know on the west side of the pond are not going to be pronouncing it that way any time soon.  But I guess it makes some kind of sense, being related to Parma, Italy.  Lots of fun facts about it on Wikipedia.
